# Convert expression using only basic logical symbols - have trouble making the two sides apart

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this expression:

$F \subseteq P(A)$

Where $F$ is some family of sets and $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$. I need to express this with using only:

$\in, \notin, =, \neq, \wedge, \vee, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow, \forall, \exists$

I first started out at writing $F$ as:

$\forall x(\exists A(\forall y \in A(y\in F)))...$

However I think the notation is totally wrong. Am I supposed to somehow use indices to describe F with only these symbols?

Comment: The perfect answer of @amWhy gives you the solution. I would add an hint: start with *definitions* and "think" with natural language; when you have found a statement that "sound good" (i.e.has the meaning that you want), then use symbols. In your example, a "family of sets" included in the power-set of $A$, is a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$, as you wrote; so apply the definition od subset (as amWhy do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the *elements* in both $F$ and $P(A)$ are *sets.*

Let the universe of discourse (universal set) be "sets".

$$F\subseteq P(A) \iff \forall x(x \in F \rightarrow x \in P(A))$$

Essentially, what we are saying is that for any set $x$, if $x\in F$, then $x \in P(A).$

Comment: yeah I wasn't sure if $x \in F$ was valid, or if I had to somehow use indices to express that $x$ can be inside each of the $A_i$ that make up $F$.